# How to calculate the offset of machine instructions using machine code itself?

Tags: assembly, x86, machine-code

I am trying to write a simple pass by pass bootloader on x86 using straight binary opcodes.

I have mapped all of the assembly mneumonics to their respective, equivalent binary prefix/primary opcodes in binary, not hex.

I realize another question similar to this one had an answer saying you must calculate the offset of the data being used as an operand in an instruction to, say, move data to a register and point to a video mode address to write directly to emulated/screen/text mode in real mode.

However, I do not understand this. How do I calculate offsets like this?

Comment: The only time you need to calculate offsets are when instructions are referring to themselves (i.e. the `jmp` instruction). References to absolute addresses work regardless of where the instruction is located.

Comment: Please show some examples of instructions you're trying to relocate.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a machine instruction set uses three types of storage addresses:

1. Absolute addresses which refer to the exact storage location of interest.
2. Base-relative addresses which, when added to the contents of a "base register", refer to the storage location of interest.
3. Instruction-relative addresses which, when added to the address of the instruction containing them, refer to the storage location of interest.

Usually the 3rd type does not need to be "relocated", since the location being referred to will generally be in the same code segment as the referring instruction, so they move together.

The second type may or may not require change upon binding/loading, depending on details of the compiled code binding scheme.

The first type will almost always require changing, but it's usually not within the instruction itself but in a separate storage word that is referred to from an instruction using one of the other two modes.

Comment: The first type won't always have to be changed - if you're referring to address `0xb8000`, the instruction encoding for that won't change, no matter where the instruction is located. It only needs to change if it's referring to something in the code.